# Countable subbase implies countable base?

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove that a topology is second-countable, meaning it has a countable base, but I have only managed to prove it has a countable subbase. I have found only affirmations that countable base is equivalent to countable subbase, but no proof.

That does seem strange to me : $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$, a countable family, doesn't $\mathcal{B}=\{A_{i_1}\cap...\cap A_{i_n}\}$ have as many elements as the parts of $\mathbb{N}$ ? Am I missing something ..?

Answer (score 3):

$\mathcal B$ has no more elements than the *finite* subsets of $\mathbb N$. And the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ is countable.

For $F\subset \mathbb N$ finite, define $n_F=\sum_{i\in F} 2^i$. This is $1-1$ on the set of finite subsets.